# ReactJs not updating nested component

Tags: forms, reactjs, tabs

I know that this is one of the most common questions in react: "why is state not updating my component correctly?" And I have searched far and wide and tried many things, but cannot seem to be able to solve this.

The most common answer to that question is that I am mutating state somewhere, but I cannot spot it.

I am trying to create a form with tabs where it is also possible to add form fields dynamically as per this article that I found: https://goshakkk.name/array-form-inputs/

Everything is working fine, except that when I remove a dynamically added form, the values of that array of forms are not updated according to the state.

My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import EditorFooter from '../../editor/moduleEditor/Footer';
import EditorHeader from '../../editor/moduleEditor/Header';


class Tab extends Component {

    render() {

        const currentTabNumber = this.props.currentTabNumber;
        const cssClass = currentTabNumber === this.props.number ? 'active' : '';

        return (
            <button className={`tab ${cssClass}`} onClick={(e) => this.props.switchTab(this.props.number)}>{this.props.name}</button>
        )
    };
};

class CourseForm extends Component {

    render() {
        const index = this.props.index;

        return (
            <div className="inner-form">
                <h3>Kurs {index}</h3>
                <button className="removeForm" onClick={this.props.handleRemoveCourse(index)}>Remove form</button>

                <h4>Kursens namn</h4>
                <input type="text" name="name" defaultValue={this.props.course.name} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange(index)} />

                <h4>Årtal</h4>
                <p className="helper-text">Exempel: 2002-2003</p>
                <input type="text" name="years" defaultValue={this.props.course.years} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange(index)} />
            </div>
        )
    };
};


class Editable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showTab: 1,
        };
    }

    switchTab = (tabNr) => {
        this.setState({ showTab: tabNr });
    }

    render() {

        const courses = this.props.courses;

        const coursesList = courses.map((course, index) =>
            <CourseForm key={index} index={index} course={course} handleInputChange={this.props.handleCourseChange} handleRemoveCourse={this.props.handleRemoveCourse} />
        );

        return (
            <div id={`${this.props.moduleItem.ModuleId}_Editor`} className="form notransition">
                <EditorHeader templateName="Simple test form" />
                <section className="form-inner">
                    <div className="tabs">
                        <Tab switchTab={this.switchTab} currentTabNumber={this.state.showTab} number={1} name="Information" />
                        <Tab switchTab={this.switchTab} currentTabNumber={this.state.showTab} number={5} name="Kurser" />
                    </div>
                    {this.state.showTab === 1 ?
                        <div className="tab-block">

                            <h4>Bild</h4>
                            <p className="helper-text">Tänk på att cv-bilden ska vara av bra kvalitet. Låt gärna en fotograf komma och fota hela projektgruppen.</p>
                            <input type="file" name="image" defaultValue={this.props.image} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />

                            <h4>Slogan</h4>
                            <p className="helper-text">Om du skulle skriva en kort reklamslogan om dig själv, vad skulle det vara?</p>
                            <textarea name="slogan" defaultValue={this.props.slogan} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}></textarea>

                        </div>
                        :
                        null
                    }
                    {this.state.showTab === 5 ?
                        <div className="tab-block">
                            {coursesList}
                            <button className="addForm" onClick={this.props.handleAddCourse}>Add form</button>
                        </div>
                        :
                        null
                    }
                </section>
                <EditorFooter {...this.props} submitForm={this.props.saveForm} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class Readable extends Component {
    render() {
        const props = this.props;

        return (
            <section className="module align-top notransition">

            </section>
        );
    }
};

class Template extends Component {
    render() {
        const props = this.props;

        return (
            <section className="module align-top">

            </section>
        );
    }
};


class SimpleTestForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            slogan: "",
            image: "",
            courses: [{ name: '', years: '' }],
        };
    }

    onAddCourseForm = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            courses: this.state.educations.concat([{ name: '', years: '' }])
        });
    }

    handleCourseChange = (index) => (e) => {
        const newCourses = this.state.courses.map((course, newIndex) => {
            if (index !== newIndex) return course;

            const target = e.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = target.name;

            return { ...course, [name]: value };
        });

        this.setState({ courses: newCourses });
    }

    handleRemoveCourse = (index) => (e) => {
        this.setState({
            courses: this.state.courses.filter((courses, newIndex) => index !== newIndex)
        });
        //this.setState( this.state );
    }

    handleAddCourse = () => {
        this.setState({
            courses: this.state.courses.concat([{ name: '', years: '' }])
        });
    }

    saveForm = (e) => {
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleInputChange = (e) => {

        const target = e.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {

        const inEditMode = this.props.mode === 'edit';
        const inTemplateMode = this.props.mode === 'template';
        const inReadMode = this.props.mode === 'read';

        return (
            <div>
                {inEditMode ?
                    <Editable {...this.props}
                        handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        onChangeEditor={this.onChangeEditor}
                        saveForm={this.saveForm}

                        handleCourseChange={this.handleCourseChange}
                        handleAddCourse={this.handleAddCourse}
                        handleRemoveCourse={this.handleRemoveCourse}

                        courses={this.state.courses}
                        slogan={this.state.slogan}
                        image={this.state.image}
                    />
                    :
                    null
                }

                {inReadMode ?
                    <Readable {...this.props}
                    />
                    :
                    null
                }

                {inTemplateMode ?
                    <Template {...this.props}
                    />
                    :
                    null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
};

module.exports = SimpleTestForm;
```

I know it is a little long and I have tried to boil it down.

My trouble is that if I add three forms under the "Kruser" tab, then fill them out, and then remove the middle one, the correct form is removed (I can see that if I log state), but its data is from the form below it. Until I switch tabs and go back to the Kurser tab, then it shows the correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the array index as key. This is one thing I could identify which may cause your problems.

If I don't have a unique identifier on my data I often use shortid to generate one. First `yarn add shortid` or `npm i --save shortid`

```
import { generate } from 'shortid';

// Update, it seems to work better if the unique id is generated on the object itself

...

handleAddCourse = () => {
    this.setState({
        courses: this.state.courses.concat([{ name: '', years: '', itemKey: generate() }])
    });
}

...

const coursesList = courses.map((course, index) =>
            <CourseForm
                key={course.itemKey}
                index={index}
                course={course}
                handleInputChange={this.props.handleCourseChange} 
                handleRemoveCourse={this.props.handleRemoveCourse} />
        );
```

Hopefully this solves your issues, if not at least you heard about this anti pattern. [Here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) you find a article on medium covering this topic with a example.

Another hint, there is a shorter and cleaner way for writing the ternarys.

*Works but hard to read*

```
{inReadMode ?
    <Readable {...this.props}
    />
    :
    null
}
```

*A lot cleaner*

```
{inReadMode &&
    <Readable {...this.props} />
}
```

See [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

Comment: Thank you! this worked, but with one exception... I had to put the `generate()` when I created the array item, not when I mapped over the array `courses: this.state.courses.concat([{ name: '', years: '', itemKey: generate() }])`

Comment: if you update the answer then I will accept it. And thanks for the tip on ternarys! :)

Comment: Updated the answer, glad it works for you, happy coding. I guess you also added it to the initial state but I guess it's self explaining to other readers

Comment: Thank you again, I hope it will be so :)